# How to prevent mutable object usage in a hash structure?

Tags: c#, hash

I feel a need to redefine Equals which would depend on mutable values of my object. Since I cannot think of any reasonable way to meet HashSet contract of unchangeable hashcode I would at least like to guard myself in any way, not to put these troublesome objects in hashed structures. Is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

All types that use hashing in .Net framework (like `Dictionary`) don't put any restrictions on "key" parameter. Non generic versions allow any `object` to be used as a key and generic once allow any type.

Using generic types (to make type of key more visible) and code reviews is only route I know.

Answer (score 1):

The `Equals` method is meant to be used for value equality. If your object is mutable, then you can write your own `IEqualityComparer`. It will use that to figure out whether the object is still equal to another object.

The `GetHashCode` method is used by `Dictionary` and `HashSet`, so if you change an object (mutate it) while it's used as a key in the collection, then the key is no longer valid.

The other approach you may want to take is to choose the key as something that is not mutable but the object itself is mutable. For example, everyone in USA has a *Social Security Number* (Social Insurance Number in Canada). You can change the person's name, date of birth etc., but the person is still the same person and you can always identify the person through the *Social Security Number*. Now you may have things other than people with *Social Security Number*, like an order, but you may have an identifier for the order in your system (database primary key) so you can use that as the key.